# Rails: Giver/Receiver records query

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism

In my application a user can give another user a penalty note:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :penaltynotes
end

class PenaltyNotes < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have set up two new user types: policeman and citizen

```
class Policeman <ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :user, as: :identifiable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Citizen <ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :user, as: :identifiable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Penalty_Notes Controller:

```
    class PenaltyNotesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_penaltynote, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      before_action :authenticate_user!
      before_filter :set_search






      def index
        unless current_user.policeman?
          redirect_to :back, :alert => "Access denied: You must be a policeman or administrator to use this resource"
        end

     ....

      def show
      end

      def import
       Penaltynotes.import(params[:file])
      end

      def new
        unless current_user.policeman?
          redirect_to :back, :alert => "Access denied: You must be a policeman or administrator to use this resource"
        end
        @penaltynote = current_user.penaltynotes.build
      end

      # GET /notes/1/edit
      def edit
      end



      def create
        @penaltynote = current_user.penaltynotes.build(note_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @penaltynote.save
            format.html { redirect_to @penaltynote, notice: 'Penalty note was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @penaltynote }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @penaltynote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
...update, destroy etc
```

Currently a user is only giving another user a penalty note, it doesn't mean anything. I would like to have it so that it is a policeman giving a citizen a note. So for example I could render how many penaltynotes a citizen has, what type they have and also how many where given to what citizen by which policeman etc. To associate the records properly with each basically.

I have been told a polymorphic relationship might be the way to go here?

I have checked around online and it's not entirely clear. Appreciate any guidance, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question got downvoted because it kind of looks like a code dump, but your question seems alright to me.

I agree the concept of "polymorphism" is kind of confusing. I personally don't use the `polymorphic: true` option in my models. I'm pretty sure you can accomplish the same thing in other ways.

For example, say you have `Police`, `Citizen`, `Human`, and `Report` classes.

I'd create the following columns:

- police.human_id (integer)
- citizen.human_id (integer)
- report.reporter_id (integer)
- report.reported_id (integer)

Then I would create different user roles as follows:

```
user = User.create(name: "max")
def change_user_to_police(user)
  Citizen.find_by(human_id: user.id).try(:destroy)
  return Police.create(human_id: user.id)
end
def change_user_to_citizen(user)
  Police.find_by(human_id: user.id).try(:destroy)
   return Citizen.create(human_id: user.id)
end
```

Some examples of performing queries:

```
police = change_user_to_police(User.create(name: "max"))
citizen = change_user_to_citizen(User.create(name: "xam"))
report = Report.create(reporter_id: police.id, reported_id: citizen.id)
def find_all_reports_by_police
  Report.where("submitter_id IN (?)", Police.all.pluck(:human_id))
end
```

I'm being a little lazy in that `find_all_reports_by_police` method above. It could probably be done in a single SQL query by using more active record methods like `.joins`.